# Set input length for checkout form magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, input

How do I go about setting the character length for input forms, preferably checkout, on magento 1.9. I'm aware that Magento has a MaxLength variable but am Unsure on how to implement it.

Comment: in which input fields to set length

Comment: First and last name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Magento1 
goto  `app/design/frontend/themename/default/template/customer/widget/name.phtml`

```
find first name - to add 'maxlength="30"' 
find last name  - to add 'maxlength="30"'
```

Comment: Thank you, that sorted it.